# What are the names of the magic methods for the operators "is" and "in"?

Tags: python, magic-methods, getattr

I would like to make bool binary operations using the magic methods for these operators. For example, I can get `a < b` as `getattr(a, '__lt__')(b)` or `a == b` as `getattr(a, '__eq__')(b)`.

Can I get `a in b` and `a is b` in such a way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`in` is `__contains__` and `is` does not have a dunder method. I strongly suggest you use the functions in the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
a < b  => operator.lt(a, b)
a == b => operator.eq(a, b)
a in b => operator.contains(a, b)
a is b => operator.is_(a, b)
```

Comment: Why would the `operator` module be preferable to the usual way?

Comment: It wouldn't be but if you need function versions of the operators the operator module is preferable to accessing dunder methods or writing your own wrappers.

Comment: I read `getattr(a, '__lt__')(b)` as asking for the function version of `a < b` which is `operator.lt(a, b)`. You can pass around `operator.lt`. I saw no attempt at definition of a class in which you would define the dunder methods.

Comment: I agree with you now. Your answer definitely provides a superior alternative to using `getattr`.

Comment: If you want `operator.is_` with the first argument already filled in, like `getattr(a, '__lt__')` already has `a` as its first argument) you can use `functools.partial`. `partial(operator.is_, a)` is a function that only takes one argument.

Answer (score 26):

For `in`, the correct dunder method is [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

There is no method for `is`, because this is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`. It compares the actual object ID used under the hood by Python, so is used to compare object identity, not object contents.  Overwriting it within a class would break Python's object model, so it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

`__contains__` is correct for `in`, with fall-back options if `__contains__` isn't defined being `__iter__` and `__getitem__`.

I am not really sure why you'd need to use `getattr` for `is` though; `is` is "defined" for *every* object in Python. There's no need to go through `operator._is` or (trying and failing) through `getattr`.

*[See the documentation on built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)*:

> The behavior of the `is` and `is not` operators *cannot be customized*; also *they can be applied to any two objects* and never raise an exception.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

According to the snippets you provided, which just grab a function and call it using `getattr(a, "function")(b)`, you already have the names of the objects you need to evaluate, just use `is` immediately; it is always available.